# 'Cancellation' in a reflective subcategory. Category Theory.

Tags: category-theory

I have been reading about reflective subcategory. First, lemme give a definition

> Def. Let $C$ be a category and let $D$ be a full subcategory. $D$ is said to be reflective if $i:D\to C$, the inclusion functor, has a left adjoint $l:C\to D$. Moreover, when $d\in D$ and $c\in C$  are such that they are isomorphic then $c\in D$.

Since we have adjunction going on, we have the unit natural trasnformation $\epsilon$ and so we have the morphisms $\epsilon_x:x\to il(x)$ for all $x\in C$.

Then I encountered a situation where there are two morphisms $f,g:l(x)\to y, y\in D$, such that $i(f)\circ\epsilon_x=i(g)\circ\epsilon_x.$ Then book proceeds by saying $f=g$ since it is a reflective subcategory, I was wondering how does it follow from reflectivity?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This follows from the fact that there’s an adjunction. There is a natural bijection $Hom(l(x), y) \to Hom(x, i(y))$. This bijection is given by $f \mapsto i(f) \circ \eta_x$ (note that the unit is typically denoted $\eta$ while the counit is denoted $\epsilon$).

Comment: @MarkSaving Ah I see! Thank you very much! So I guess it did not fully use the fact that it is a reflective subcategory right? only that there is an adjunction happening?